# I'm unable to automate toggle button based on its existing state

Tags: selenium-webdriver, toggle, ui-automation

in my case I want to first check of the toggle button is on/off. If its off then I would like to turn it on and if its already on then it should remain on. I have used isSelected,isEnabled and isDisplayed but none of this method detests the status of the button.

```
**Following is my trial code:**

if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='toggle-handle btn btn-default'])[2]")).isSelected()) {
System.out.println("is turned on");
}
else {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='feed-toggle-container brand-integrity-site-visibility'])[2]")).click();
}
```

HTML:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Atlas Copco Brand Integrity Site</td>
    <td>ac.website.com</td>
    <td>
        <div class="feed-toggle-container brand-integrity-site-visibility">
            <div class="toggle btn btn-default off" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 73px; height: 32px;">
                <input class="feed-toggle" data-url="https://admin.stage.cwsplatform.com/api/brand-integrity-site/7" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" name="visible_to_dealer" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <div class="toggle-group">
                    <label class="btn btn-success toggle-on">On</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">Off</label><span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://ac.website.com.live.stage.cwsplatform.com/cws-login">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Manage Content</button>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://ac.website.com.demo.stage.cwsplatform.com/cws-login">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Manage Content</button>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

feed-toggle-container brand-integrity-site-visibility  . Clicking on this class basically turns on and off the button. If its on it will turn it off and vice-versa. Using the above code is just turning off the On status instead of just leaving it to the on state.

HTML when the button is On:

```
<label class="btn btn-success toggle-on">On</label>
```

HTML when button is Off:

```
<label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">Off</label>
```

Comment: @h desaiu Please Inspect element and provide both HTML when Button is ON and OFF

Comment: As @IshitaShah mentioned, you need to update the question with the HTML of the button both while 1) ON and 2)OFF

Comment: @IshitaShah I have html at the bottom of my question . Please review it. Appreciate your help

Comment: @hdesaiu It seems active class is toggle-Off, So it should be OFF. Similarly check for ON class when its active, class=btn btn-success active toggle-on "active" is there or not ?

Comment: @IshitaShah class=btn btn-success active toggle-on "active" is not present. When "ON" button is active it just shows <label class="btn btn-success toggle-on">On</label>

Answer (score 1):

You can perform below scenario for same:

- You need to first check its current state
- You can check based on class value
- After getting class value, You can check and verify its state
- And so you can handle user defined actions

---

```
//This is to Locate on label
By locateOnLabel = By.xpath("//div[@class='toggle-group']//label[contains(text(),'On')]");


//This is to Locate off label    
By locateOffLabel = By.xpath("//div[@class='toggle-group']//label[contains(text(),'Off')]");

//Retrieve their class, it given identification whether its On/Off
String getLabelONClass = driver.findElement(locateOnLabel).getAttribute("class");
String getLabelOFFClass = driver.findElement(locateOffLabel).getAttribute("class");

//compare class values, and Perform actions
if(getLabelOFFClass.equals("btn btn-default active toggle-off)) {      
       Click that Webelement if you want to turn on 
}
   else if (getLabelONClass.equals("btn btn-success toggle-on")) {                   
       You can notify message, That Button is already ON
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but I'm still facing problems. I tried to incorporate the same code above. But the action that's mentioned in the if loop always takes place. It never goes to the else-if loop. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Based on the above code, even if the button is already turned on it will go and click the web element because it performs action mentioned in the if loop and never goes to the else if loop.